# Matlab gui image incorrectly blue

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I am creating a GUI containing an image using the following code:

```
try
    Imagenamehere = imread('Imagenamehere.jpg');
    axes(handles.Logo)
    image(Imagenamehere)
    set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
catch
    msgbox('Please download all contents from the zipped file into working directory.')
end
```

The image shows up but for some reason is completely coloured blue as if put through a blue filter. I don't think it would be wise to upload the image but it is a simple logo coloured black and white.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size, type (probably `uint8`) and range of your image. It sounds like for some reason your images are being displayed with `colormap` as jet (the default), and possibly also that your range is not what MATLAB expects (e.g. 0 to 1 not 0 to 255), resulting in all your values being relatively low (blue on the jet colormap).

"black and white" is just one way of interpreting an image file which contains only two colors. MATLAB makes several assumptions when you pass data into a display function like `image`. If you don't specify colormap and image data range, it will make a guess based off things like data type.

One possibility is that your logo file is an indexed image. In these cases you need to do:

```
[Imagenamehere map] = imread('Imagenamehere.jpg');
colormap(map);
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess it was an indexed image because I used the code you suggested and the logo now appears as expected!

Comment: I have just realised that this has created a new problem! The rest of my figures which were previously coloured are now black and white?

Comment: type is uint8. getting 500x542 for cdata size and 16x3 for colourmap size.

Comment: If you have multiple different images to display in one figure/gui, some of which are rgb (truecolor) and some of which are indexed, check each image type with `imfinfo`, and change indexed images to rgb using `ind2rgb`

Comment: I'm afraid when I use imfinfo I get: 'Error using imfinfo (line 80)
Expected FILENAME to be one of these types:

char

Instead its type was uint8.'

Comment: And when I use ind2rgb(Imagenamehere) in my code I get the catch msgbox. Sorry I might be just missing some very basic points but I am quite new to this.

Comment: Use `help functioname` at the command line to see the right syntax. `imfinfo` needs to be called on the filename before you load anything in.  `ind2rgb` needs you to give it both the image name and the colormap.